Apprehend major shirk due to waswas
Assalamu alaikum brother. I am suffering from waswas. I apprehend to commit major shirk due to waswas. What should I do? Have I left Islam? Please must reply my question.

Do you mean you are suffering from devilish whispers that taunt you?
If so what that is what repentance is for.
First start with seeking refuge with Allah because this is a trap set by satan to get you to deviate from the straight path. Ask Allah for forgiveness as He is All Forgiving. Then repent and make a conscious effort to monitor your thoughts  and every time
You feel Waswasa rising, you seek refuge with Allah from satan and his schemes. There’s this saying, seek the Lord and satan shall flee.

It's a common challenge faced by many Muslims. The important thing to remember is that waswas does not mean you have left Islam. It's a test from Allah, and He will help you overcome it.
Here are some steps you can take to manage waswas:
Consult with a knowledgeable Islamic scholar or counselor who can provide guidance and support.
Engage in regular remembrance of Allah through dhikr. This can help strengthen your faith and ward off negative thoughts.
Recite verses of the Quran and make supplications seeking refuge in Allah from the evil whispers of Satan.  
Do not engage with or give attention to the waswas. The more you focus on it, the stronger it can become.
Remember that Allah is merciful and forgiving. He will not hold you accountable for thoughts that you are struggling to control.
It's important to be patient and persistent in your efforts to overcome waswas. With Allah's help, you can overcome this challenge and strengthen your faith.
Remember, you are not alone in this. Many Muslims have faced similar challenges and have found strength and guidance in their faith.

